# Unable to bind ViewModel to UserControl

Tags: c#, winui-3

I have a UserControl that I setup to drop a Toolbar into any Page in my application.

```
public sealed partial class Toolbar : UserControl
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ViewModelProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(ViewModel), typeof(ViewModelBase_Toolbar<object>), typeof(Toolbar), new PropertyMetadata(null));
    public ViewModelBase_Toolbar<object> ViewModel
    {
        get => (ViewModelBase_Toolbar<object>)GetValue(ViewModelProperty);
        set => SetValue(ViewModelProperty, value);
    }
 
    public Toolbar()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

So that different applications can customize the functionality of the Add/Edit buttons, I am just passing the Current Apps ViewModel as a DependencyProperty. Here is the base ViewModel & an example of the customized ViewModel.

```
public abstract class ViewModelBase_Toolbar<T> : BindableBase where T : new()
{        
    public virtual void Add()
    {
        // Base functionality
    }
}

public class UsersViewModel : ViewModelBase_Toolbar<User>
{
    public virtual void Add()
    {
        // Customized Functionality
    }        
}
```

I am getting the following compile error when I try to bind the UsersViewModel to the Toolbar:

> Error WMC1121 Invalid binding assignment : Cannot directly bind type 'App.ViewModels.UsersViewModel' to 'App.ViewModels.ViewModelBase_Toolbar(System.Object)'. Use a cast, converter or function binding to change the type

The only way I got the toolbar working was to change it to receive ViewModelBase_Toolbar<App.Models.User> instead of ViewModelBase_Toolbar. Is there some better solution so that I can still have a completely dynamic Toolbar control?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can bind commands to your `ToolBar` control.

**ToolBar.xaml.cs**

```cs
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml;
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace UserControls;

public sealed partial class ToolBar : UserControl
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty AddCommandProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        nameof(AddCommand),
        typeof(ICommand),
        typeof(ToolBar),
        new PropertyMetadata(default));

    public ToolBar()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    public ICommand AddCommand
    {
        get => (ICommand)GetValue(AddCommandProperty);
        set => SetValue(AddCommandProperty, value);
    }
}
```

**ToolBar.xaml**

```xml
<UserControl
    x:Class="UserControls.ToolBar"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="using:UserControls"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Button
            x:Name="AddButton"
            Command="{x:Bind AddCommand, Mode=OneWay}"
            Content="Add" />
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

**MainPage.xaml**

```xml
<local:ToolBar AddCommand="{x:Bind ViewModel.AddCommand, Mode=OneWay}" />
```

Comment: I would rather just pass the ViewModel in though as there will eventually be alot of buttons on the toolbar. So I don't want to have to bind a bunch of commands every time when I can just pass the ViewModel. The problem is I have so far been unable to pass a ViewModel that is a child of ViewModelBase_Toolbar<T> to the DependencyProperty.

Comment: Essentially, I want to be able to do this:
        ViewModelBase_Toolbar<object> ViewModel = new UsersViewModel();